# Print a Chart n times using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I need to print a given char n times using recusion. I know that the base case would b when n is 1 returns the chart itself, but then I dont know how to print the char n times using recursion :(

No for loops or while are allowed.

Comment: Do you even know how recursion works?

Comment: "Chart" (in title) or `char` (in question)? (Autocorrect strikes again it would seem...)

Comment: Print the chart in your function. Pass n in your function. Call your function from your function. And subtract one from n in the function call.

Comment: I do I have a methor call printTimes( chart b, int n) { if (n==1) prints b else prinTimes( b , n) but I cant multiply b by n so Im stuck!!! :(

Comment: If you want to understand recursion, first you must understand recursion.

Comment: Thats very helpful CsBalazHungary.... lol

Comment: Please correct the spelling in the title, update description of your question indicating the use of loops is not allowed. I had to read all of your comments to realize you can't use loops. You have to state all the givens to receive a good answer with the least amount of edits.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is simple. In recursion you call the function repeatedly and you have a base case. The base case is used to return from the function.

```
public class Example {

    private static int n = 34;
    private static char example = 'c';

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of times you want to print a char.");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        printNTimes();
    }

    public static void printNTimes() {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(n + "\t" + example);
        n--;
        printNTimes();
    }
}
```

Comment: They dont let me use a while or for loop.

Comment: @IvanChafardeth Now take it without while loop.

Answer (score 0):

How recursion works:

Your method accomplishes a task *once*. If required, the method *calls itself* with *different* parameters, resulting in the same task being repeated but eventually with a different outcome.

A method that uses recursion to print a given character `n` times

```
//function takes a character and the number of times to print
public void printChar(char c, int times){
    //print the character
    System.out.print(c);
    if (times > 1){
        /*
        * only print the character again if required
        * if the number of times in this instance of the function is 1,
        * then the next time will be 0, implying that the printing is done
        */
        printChar(c, times - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but they dont let me use a for loop to print the chart n times so I dont know what to do.

Comment: Im not saying that there is one in your code... Im jsut saying I dont know how to fill in the method without a for loop... sorry.

Comment: Use this,
System.out.print(String.format("%010d",0).replace("0","Dilip\n"));